How can I convert R tibble character variable (with both characters and integers) to integer type with integers and NA_integer_?
I have a set of data frames with a variable age. In some data frames, age is numeric type (containing integer age values, and -1 and 99 as missing values). In others, it is character type (containing integer age values, "-1", "99", and text like "missing"). Given a character type age variable, I define age_fix where "-1", "99", and "missing" are defined as NA_integer_ and all other options (which are numeric age-range values) are defined as integer types with as.integer().
Why are the NAs introduced by coersion if everything is integer type? I assume it has to do with the processing of the value "missing".
And is this something which should be corrected?
library(tidyverse) # for data frame manipulation

# tibble with age variable 
df <- tibble(
  # 99, missing, and -1 refer to missing values
  age = c("99", "missing", "8", "-1")
)

# Now I would like to convert c("99", "-1", "missing")
  # to NA_integer_ and other integer values to integer type
# Note that in full context, I am mapping over multiple
  # data frames, some with character age variables and others 
  # with numeric type age variables. So I convert everything 
  # to character and then back to integer (or NA_integer_)

try <- df |> 
  mutate(age_fix = if_else(
    # str_to_lower() because strings may include uppercase
    # as.character() to make all values of `df$age` character
      # across data frames
    str_to_lower(as.character(age)) %in% c(
      "99", "-1", "missing"
    ), 
    NA_integer_, # if age is one of missing options
    as.integer(age) # otherwise, convert to integer type
  ))


#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `age_fix = if_else(...)`.
#> Caused by warning in `if_else()`:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion

Created on 2024-05-28 with reprex v2.1.0

if_else will evaluate all the values' TRUE and FALSE results and output the one that corresponds to the test. So when your FALSE result is based on as.integer(age) that will be coerced to NA for values like "missing". In that case it's fine since both TRUE and FALSE will be NA_integer, but that's why you see the warning. See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5341 for a prior user's question on that behavior.

Try to replace NA values with NA, and then convert to integer, this works for both base::ifelse and dplyr::if_else:
df %>% 
  mutate(age_fix1 = as.integer(ifelse(age %in% c("99", "missing", "-1"), NA, age)),
         age_fix2 = as.integer(if_else(age %in% c("99", "missing", "-1"), NA, age)))

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   age     age_fix1 age_fix2
#   <chr>      <int>    <int>
# 1 99            NA       NA
# 2 missing       NA       NA
# 3 8              8        8
# 4 -1            NA       NA


To illustrate the comment made by @Jon Spring a bit further, I created a modified if_else() based on the source code:
my_if_else <- function (condition, true, false, missing = NULL, ..., ptype = NULL, 
                        size = NULL) 
{
  rlang:::check_dots_empty0(...)
  dplyr:::check_logical(condition)
  conditions <- list(condition = condition, !condition)
  values <- list(true = true, false = false)
  return(values) # modified to return `values` early
}

If we run your logic on this modified code we get:
# Reproduce your warning 
output <- my_if_else(str_to_lower(as.character(df$age)) %in% c("99", "-1", "missing"), NA_integer_, as.integer(df$age))
# Warning message:
# In my_if_else(str_to_lower(as.character(df$age)) %in% c("99", "-1",  :
#   NAs introduced by coercion

output
# $true
# [1] NA
# 
# $false
# [1] 99 NA -1  8

class(output$false)
# [1] "integer"

When the condition you supply is TRUE the corresponding value from $true is taken and when FALSE the corresponding value of $false is taken, but either way both are computed.
Here the warning comes from the creation of $false. Specifically, the attempt is made to coerce "missing" to an integer and when it cannot it returns NA but throws a warning:
# cannot coerce "missing" to an integer
as.integer(df$age[2])
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 

# coerces successfully, no warning
as.integer(df$age[-2])
# [1] 99 -1  8

Even though your condition for "missing" is TRUE its corresponding FALSE value is still computed and that results in your warning.

With this understanding, there is nothing wrong with your code in this specific instance and you could ignore the warning. However, it might be best to be explicit and correct the issue behind the warning. @zx8754 demonstrates a few ways that revolve around replacing values with NA then converting to integer. This works because NA propagates (operations involving NA return NA) in R and does not cause a coercion warning since it is not being coerced:
as.integer(NA)
# [1] NA

Another potential solution would be to iterate over each value and use if-else logic, which does not compute the FALSE output:
df |>
  mutate(age_fix = map_int(str_to_lower(age), \(x) if (x %in% c("99", "-1", "missing")) NA else as.integer(x)))
#   age     age_fix
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 99           NA
# 2 missing      NA
# 3 -1           NA
# 4 8             8

